# What is the Flex/AS3/E4X equivalent of this xpath query?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, xpath, e4x

Given this document:

```
<doc>
    <element>
        <list>
            <key attr='val'/>
        </list>
    </element>
    <element>
        <list>
            <key attr='other'/>
        </list>
    </element>
    <element>
        <list/>
    </element>
</doc>
```

I want an e4x equivalent of the xpath `//element[list/key/@attr="val"]`. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
..element.(list.key.@attr == "val")
```

Comment: What will that do in cases where a key element exists without an @attr attribute? I know that XPath returns no node for that, but e4x craters with a missing attribute error type for simple expressions. Does that happen here, too?

Comment: In my experience if the attribute is missing nothing will be returned, no error will be thrown.

Comment: This will cause no problems in AS3. There is one issue in JavaScript. As long as the attribute is being checked on a child node (whether that even exists or not) in the filter, no errors will be thrown. `..(@bar=="baz")` would throw an error as not every element has a `bar` attribute, so you would want to try `..(function::attribute("bar")=="baz")` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

```
xmlVarName.element.list.key.(@attr=="val");
```

alternative

```
xmlVarName..key.(@attr=="val");
```

Comment: No, that will return the key nodes. The xpath I showed returns the element nodes that have a particular key attribute.

Comment: `//element` isn't `.element` (which is `/element`). It would be `..element`.

Comment: I misunderstood what you were looking for, sorry, not familiar with xpath. Elijah has an answer, another is to call the parent() method like xmlVarName.element.list.key.(@attr=="val").parent().parent() (though Elijah's is cleaner).

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that

```
..element.(list.key.@attr == "val")
```

Can fail if the **key** nodes don't all have **@attr**.

The safest (although in my experience, not 100% successful) method to extract your node list would be.

```
..element.(list.key.attribute("attr") == "val")
```

However, I have had problems with e4x and conditional expressions, (AS3 implementation, Mozilla seems better.) but it seems to be down to the xml source.